# How to access element in postgresql string array

Tags: regex, postgresql

`regex_matches` returns a string array : `{first match, second match`}. How do I access the elements within it? I have tried:

```
regex_matches('mystring', 'my string pattern')[0]
regex_matches('mystring', 'my string pattern') as url[0]
regex_matches('mystring', 'my string pattern') as url, url[0]
```

Nothing works. Do I really need to do a string function to replace the two braces? That seems pretty clunky

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to use extra parenthesis:

```
postgres=# select regexp_matches('123 333'::text, '\d{3}'::text, 'g');
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {123}
 {333}
(2 rows)

postgres=# select (regexp_matches('123 333'::text, '\d{3}'::text, 'g'))[1];
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 123
 333
(2 rows)
```